# C++0x lambda capture by value always const?

Tags: c++, lambda, constants, c++11

Is there any way to capture by value, and make the captured value non-const?  I have a library functor that I would like to capture & call a method that is non-const but should be.

The following doesn't compile but making foo::operator() const fixes it.

```
struct foo
{
  bool operator () ( const bool & a )
  {
    return a;
  }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  foo afoo;

  auto bar = [=] () -> bool
    {
      afoo(true);
    };

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Use mutable.

```
auto bar = [=] () mutable -> bool ....
```

Without mutable you are declaring the operator () of the lambda object const.

Answer (score -5):

There is alternative way to using **mutable** (solution proposed by Crazy Eddie).

With **[=]** your block captures all objects by values. You can use **[&]** to capture all objects by reference:

```
auto bar = [&] () -> bool
```

Or you can capture by reference only certain object **[=, &afoo]**:

```
auto bar = [=, &afoo] () -> bool
```

Refer to this page for fore details (*Explanation* section): 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: This does completely different things.  They are not interchangeable.  This doesn't respond to the OP's question.

Comment: The problem of this solution is that it does not work for captured local variables destroyed before the lambda is executed (for example, when you start a detached std::thread).