# const XX discards qualifiers [- fpermissive]

Tags: c++, c++11

In code snippet 1 below, mKnownSRList is defined as follows:

```
std::vector<EndPointAddr*> mKnownSRList;
```

I am getting a compilation error shown in code snippet 2. Can you tell me what's wrong with this code please? The content of the getTipcAddress() and compareTo functions are shown in code snippet 3 and 4 below.

**CODE SNIPPET 1 (Compilation error is marked)**

```
void 
ServiceRegistrarAPI::removeKnownSR(EndPointAddr & srEndPointAddr)
{
   auto last = 
   std::remove_if(mKnownSRList.begin(),
                  mKnownSRList.end(),
                 [srEndPointAddr]( EndPointAddr* o )
                 { 
                    //LINE 355 is the following
            EndPointTipcAddr myTipcAddress = srEndPointAddr.getTipcAddress();
                EndPointTipcAddr otherTipcAddress = o->getTipcAddress();

            return (myTipcAddress.compareTo(otherTipcAddress));
         });

    if(*last != nullptr)
    {
     delete *last;
    }

    mKnownSRList.erase(last, mKnownSRList.end());    
}
```

**SNIPPET 2 (Compilation Error)**

```
  ServiceRegistrarAPI.cpp:355:72: error: passing ‘const EndPointAddr’ as ‘this’   argument of ‘EndPointTipcAddr& EndPointAddr::getTipcAddress()’ discards qualifiers [-  fpermissive]
```

**CODE SNIPPET 3 (getTipcAddress function)**

```
EndPointTipcAddr & getTipcAddress() { return mTipcAddress; }
```

**CODE NIPPET 4 (compareTo function)**

```
  bool

  EndPointTipcAddr::compareTo(EndPointTipcAddr &rhs) 
  {     
      if( (mType == rhs.getType()) && (mInstanceNo == rhs.getInstanceNo()) )
      {
        return true;
      } 

      return false;
  }
```

Comment: Haven't considered this in detail, but I believe [this will be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835626/c0x-lambda-capture-by-value-always-const).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predicate function (third argument of `std::remove_if`) is not allowed to modify the object. All methods called on the iterator must be `const`. See [this documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/):

> The function shall not modify its argument.

You can set `getTipcAddress` to be `const` if you are returning a copy of a value or a `const` pointer.

Answer (score 5):

See S5.1.2.5:

> The closure type for a lambda-expression has a public inline function
>   call operator (13.5.4) whose parameters and return type are described
>   by the lambda-expression’s parameter-declaration-clause and
>   trailingreturn- type respectively. This function call operator is
>   declared const (9.3.1) if and only if the lambdaexpression’s
>   parameter-declaration-clause is not followed by mutable. It is neither
>   virtual nor declared volatile. Default arguments (8.3.6) shall not be
>   specified in the parameter-declaration-clause of a lambdadeclarator.
>   Any exception-specification specified on a lambda-expression applies
>   to the corresponding function call operator. An
>   attribute-specifier-seq in a lambda-declarator appertains to the type
>   of the corresponding function call operator. [ Note: Names referenced
>   in the lambda-declarator are looked up in the context in which the
>   lambda-expression appears. —end note ]

Basically, the implication is the operator() of the functor that is generated is `const` by default, and you've captured by value, and this captured variable is a member of the generated functor.

So, you've two options:

1. Capture by reference, instead of by value.
2. Change your lambda to the following (note the `mutable` following the parameter declaration clause):

   `[srEndPointAddr](EndPointAddr* o) mutable { ... }`

Comment: +1e6! At last someone explained why it really happened, not some mambo-jambo about everything else.

Answer (score 1):

In short you get this error because you invoke a non-const method on a const instance in this case: `srEndPointAddr` is const but you invoke the non-const method `getTipcAddress` on it. The solution for you would be to declare this method const as it seems a simple getter and probably will not modify the object.

Comment: But the question is, "why is it a const instance"?

Comment: @juanchopanza hmm I tought the question is how to fix this error.