# `decltype((variable))` has `const` qualifier inside lambda with capture by value?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void print_type() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main () {
    float x, &r = x;
    std::cout << "capture by value" << std::endl;
    [=] {
        print_type<decltype(x)>();
        print_type<decltype((x))>();
        print_type<decltype(r)>();
        print_type<decltype((r))>();
    }();

    std::cout << "capture by reference" << std::endl;
    [&] {
        print_type<decltype(x)>();
        print_type<decltype((x))>();
        print_type<decltype(r)>();
        print_type<decltype((r))>();
    }();
}
```

The output of clang 10.0 is (GCC 10.0 has a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66672)):

```
capture by value
void print_type() [T = float]
void print_type() [T = const float &]
void print_type() [T = float &]
void print_type() [T = const float &]
capture by reference
void print_type() [T = float]
void print_type() [T = float &]
void print_type() [T = float &]
void print_type() [T = float &]
```

I wonder why `decltype((x))` and `decltype((r))` have a `const` qualifier when they are captured by value.  When they are captured by reference, they don't have a `const` qualifier.

Any idea?

And what's the common use case of `decltype((variable))` inside and outside lambda?

Edit#1:

Few flagged this as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764153/lambda-why-are-captured-by-value-values-const-but-capture-by-reference-values).

The post doesn't explain why double parenthesis adds `const` to `decltype`'s deduction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lambda: Why are captured-by-value values const, but capture-by-reference values not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764153/lambda-why-are-captured-by-value-values-const-but-capture-by-reference-values) or [C++0x lambda capture by value always const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835626/c0x-lambda-capture-by-value-always-const), etc.

Comment: "_GCC 10.0 has a bug_" What bug?

Comment: @underscore_d added the link to the bug report.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks for your links.  both links pointed out when lambda is captured by value without `mutable`, we should think it as `operator()() const` and the value captured as a non static variable.  However, those 2 links don't explain why using double parenthesis will add `const` quantifier to the reference type.

Comment: @KamilCuk would you mind elaborating?  The link you attached doesn't mention such conversion...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115744/significance-of-parentheses-in-decltypec I made a typo in that comment. It's because "lvalue-to-rvalue" conversion (not the other way round). https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Lvalue_to_rvalue_conversion Well, what's there to elaborate? A rvalue cannot be modified, so it's `const`. A lvalue can be modified so it's not `const`. Variable name is treated as variable type. Adding braces makes it an expression.

Comment: @KamilCuk ? Neither conversion is relevant... `decltype(variable)` is different from `decltype((variable))` [because `decltype` directly depends on the syntax of its argument expression](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1.3). The mention of `decltype` in your quote says "stuff like `int f(int); int *p = nullptr; decltype(f(*p)) x = 0;` doesn't crash, even though `f(*p)` looks like it calls for the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (i.e. read) of `*nullptr`". `decltype` of an rvalue expression gives either `T&&` or `T` (for xvalues or prvalues, resp.) None of the `decltype`s are on rvalues.