# value turned const in lambda capture?

Tags: c++, lambda, shared-ptr, capture

I have this simple code:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> s;

auto bla = [s]() {
    s.reset();
};
```

What I meant this to do is that the shared_ptr be captured by the lambda and then reset once the lambda is called.
Compiling this with VS yields the following error:

`error C2662: 'void std::shared_ptr<std::string>::reset(void) noexcept': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const std::shared_ptr<std::string>' to 'std::shared_ptr<std::string> &' 1>...: message : Conversion loses qualifiers`

What gives? How come the `shared_ptr` turns to `const shared_ptr`?

Comment: `auto bla = mutable [s]() { ... }` like this maybe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When capturing by copy, all captured objects are implicitly `const`. You have to explicitly mark lambda as `mutable` to disable that:

```
auto bla = [s]() mutable {
    s.reset();
};
```

Also, if you want to reset actual `s` and not a copy, you want to capture by reference. You don't need `mutable` when capturing by reference, in this case constness is inferred from the actual object:

```
auto bla = [&s]() {
    s.reset();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++17, you can do this:

```cpp
vector<int>a;
auto lambda = [a=std::as_const(a)](){};
```

It comes from this: [Lambda: Why are captured-by-value values const, but capture-by-reference values not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16764153)