# error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue when using find_if

Tags: c++, lambda

I have two vectors of classes that contain mainly strings, and I'm trying to keep track of how many times there was a match between two vectors. I kept an `int` counter in one of the two public classes (necessary for another function). However, `std::find_if` doesn't seem to allow me to modify nor assign this counter variable.

Following is the `std::find_if` search algorithm:

```
for (Vector1& v1 : vector1) {
    auto res = find_if(vector2.begin(), vector2.end(),
        [=](Vector2 v2) {
            if (v2.code == v1.code) {
                v1.counter++; // <-- where the error occurs
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    );
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why this happens; my speculation is that the third parameter for the `find_if` algorithm takes in a `const` value. But that shouldn't affect my `vector1`, right?

I used nested ranged for-loops instead, and it works perfectly. However, I'd like to try using this `find_if` algorithm instead...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a problem with capture/pass by value/reference.

It should be `[&]` or `[&v1]` - variables captured by value are non-`mutable` by default, and lambda's `operator()` is `const`. [You could use the `mutable` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835645/3552770) to fix the error, which makes `operator()` non-`const`, but you wouldn't see the changes made to `v1` anyways.

Additionally, you should be passing by `Vector2 const& v2`, `auto const&` or `auto &&` in sake of avoiding making a copy.

Together:

```
[&v1](Vector2 const& v2) { ... }
```

---

> I'd like to try using this `find_if` algorithm instead...

But that's not what it's for. If you aren't going to use the returned iterator, don't do it. You should be getting a warning. Use loops for simple iteration.