# Lambda capture by value and the "mutable" keyword

Tags: c++, lambda

The need of the keyword `mutable` in lambdas, is source of great confusion.

Consider the code:

```
int x = 10;

function<void()> lambda = [=]() mutable {x++; cout << "Inside lambda: x = " << x << "\n";};

cout << "Before lambda: x = " << x << "\n";
lambda();
cout << "After  lambda: x = " << x << "\n\n";
```

Output:

```
Before lambda: x = 10
Inside lambda: x = 11
After  lambda: x = 10
```

As we can see, the variable `x` stays unchanged after the lambda, so there are no side effects.

However, if we "forget" the keyword **mutable**, we get an error.

Being the argument passing by value the default in C++, it doesn't make sense for me the need of the *mutable* keyword.

Can someone write (even in pseudo code) the class generated by the compiler, in place of the lambda?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++0x lambda capture by value always const?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835626/c0x-lambda-capture-by-value-always-const)

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) the `mutable` specifier *allows the lambda to modify the parameters captured by copy and to call their non-const member functions*. It doesn't affect variables captured by reference.

> Can someone write (even in pseudo code) the class generated by the compiler, in place of the lambda?

It's not that easy to give a general case, but we can define something that is valid in your specific case.
The generated class would probably look like:

```
struct Lambda {
    void operator()() { x++; }
    int x{10};
};
```

If you remove the `mutable` specifier, the function operator is defined as `const`:

```
struct Lambda {
    void operator()() const { x++; }
    int x{10};
};
```

For simplicity I've initialized `x` with the given value (10) and made it public, but it's obviously initialized by copy using the variable captured from the surrounding context and not accessible from outside the function operator.
Its type is deduced as well from the variable used to initialize it as if you do:

```
auto lambda_x = x;
```

See [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Lambda
{
public:
   Lambda(const Lambda&);
   ~Lambda();

   // the main functor operator, const when lambda not mutable
   R operator()(Args args) const;

   // Only present for non-capture lambda         
   operator PlainCFunctionType () const; 

   // Only present for non-capture  lambda         
   PlainCFunctionType operator+() const;
private:
   // Gets called when lambda created, but you can't call it yourself
   Lambda(Captures captures...); 

   Captures captures;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not really writing code in an object-oriented way, but anyhow.
Normally the external variables added by [=] are const values. By adding the mutable keyword, you create local modifiable copies of them.
You could use [&] instead to capture by reference.

Comment: Using [&] alter the variable value after the lambda. In my code the capture is by value.