# Can not capture a random distribution and generator by value in lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

The following code works fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(5.0, 2.0);
    std::vector<double> v(100);

    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&] () { return distribution(generator); });

    return 0;
}
```

However, changing the capture list of the lambda to `[=]` or `[&, distribution]` or `[&, generator]` causes

```
rand.cpp:9:59: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const std::normal_distribution<double>'
error: assigning to 'double' from incompatible type 'void'
```

Are there some kinds of objects can not be captured by value in a lambda ?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like `std::normal_distribution<double>::operator()` is not `const`.
So you have to add `mutable` keyword to your lambda:

```
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [=] () mutable { 
   return distribution(generator); 
});

std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&, distribution] () mutable { 
   return distribution(generator); 
});
```

These both work fine.

Answer (score 6):

In general, capture by values requires the object to be copyable. Both `std::default_random_generator` and `std::normal_distribution` are copyable, so this shouldn't be a problem here.

[Lambda captures are always const values or const references.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056454/lambda-capture-by-value-and-the-mutable-keyword) Random number generation is inherently stateful, so the called `operator()` cannot be const because it may modify the object state. The error message cryptically reports this by saying that there is no function to call on a `const std::normal_distribution<double>`.

If you want to modify the captured objects, you have to declare the lambda as mutable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(5.0, 2.0);
    std::vector<double> v(100);

    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [generator, distribution] () mutable { return distribution(generator); });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, the error message is just a bit hard to understand. Is it good practice to always use `&` for none built-in types ?

Comment: @displayname - it depends, but yes, in this particular case you definitely don't want to work off a copy of the `generator`.